# Nginx editing php.ini changes no reflecting

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, php5, php-fpm

**phpinfo** says the file location is `/etc/php5/fpm/php.ini`.

Additional `.ini` files parsed

```
   /etc/php5/fpm/conf.d/curl.ini,
   /etc/php5/fpm/conf.d/gd.ini,
   /etc/php5/fpm/conf.d/mcrypt.ini,
   /etc/php5/fpm/conf.d/mysql.ini,
   /etc/php5/fpm/conf.d/mysqli.ini,
   /etc/php5/fpm/conf.d/pdo.ini,
   /etc/php5/fpm/conf.d/pdo_mysql.ini,
   /etc/php5/fpm/conf.d/xcache.ini
```

Looking in them none of them have anything that deals with `post_max_filesize` or `upload_max_filesize`.

I edit this in the `php.ini` file and restart both the **nginx** and **php5-fpm** service.   The changes do not happen.  The files are still edited.   I have tried rebooting the computer.

Does **NGINX** cache this somewhere that I need to delete in order for these changes to be made live?

I have tried `php -i | grep ".ini"`

and it tells me the path for `php.ini is Path => /etc/php5/cli/`

The phpinfo() tells me its `/etc/php5/fpm/`

I have edited both with no luck.

if I do `php -i | grep "post_max"`
 it tells me its **20M**, phpinfo still says **8M**.

Comment: "I have tried php -i | grep ".ini"
and it tells me the path for php.ini is /etc/php5/cli/
The phpinfo() tells me its /etc/php5/fpm/"
This is because phpinfo() is executed by the web server via FPM. When you run php from terminal you're using CLI (by definition).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you tried to put your php.ini under **/etc/php5/fpm/php.ini**? This is normally the default location that php reads from, if I understand php5-fpm correctly.

Comment: That's where it is located at.  The changes to it are not happening.

Comment: Do you perhaps have logs for php5-fpm? Is there nothing in your error logs?

Comment: Nothing useful, just that it was reloaded over and over again when I was trying to fix the problem.

Comment: There was ntohing in the logs, but I did find http://serverfault.com/questions/450460/php-ini-error-on-error-reporting

Answer (score 26):

You need to restart it. I use 7.0 so change the 7.0 to your version.

```
sudo systemctl restart php7.0-fpm
```

Comment: This worked for me when the other answer didn't.

Comment: Works to me, after changing /etc/php/7.x/fpm/php.ini

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem in Centos 7 I used nginx as the webserver. I restared php-fpm service and my problem solved. the reason is nginx use php-fpm service for handling php the only way to reflect your changes is restart php-fpm service.

you need to run **systemctl restart php-fpm**

Answer (score 0):

For me (using CentOS) I had to do the following to take effect of `php.ini` change:

```
systemctl restart httpd.service
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using something like **wodby** (`docker4php`  or `docker4drupal`) or **lando** or trying to find an answer "why php.ini doesn't work" (like me), these tools are using their own way to pass configuration into php

https://github.com/wodby/php#php-and-php-fpm-configuration

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).