# php.ini Error on "error_reporting"

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, php.ini, php-fpm

I found the error by trying to change php.ini.

```
 root:/etc/php5/fpm# php5-fpm -i | grep "post_max"
 PHP:  syntax error, unexpected '|' in /etc/php5/fpm/php.ini on line 110
 post_max_size => 8M => 8M
```

Line 110 is

```
 109: error_reporting
 110:       Default Value: E_ALL | ~E_NOTICE
```

I had it set to E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE but it was erring then as well. Saying unexpected '&'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me as if you've just uncommented some lines in `php.ini` without understanding that they're not meant to be uncommented; they're advisory text on how to set variables.  If you want to change the value of `error_reporting`, try instead

```
error_reporting = "E_ALL | ~E_NOTICE"
```

Comment: Still error, now it shifted the error to the  "

Comment: @Iscariot did you comment the lines back out?  Lines 109 and 110 that you pasted (and other lines like that) are instructions to you, that need to have the comment marks so that php doesn't think its instructions to it.